# How to white spray paint bath window for privacy?

Tags: bathroom, paint, cleaning, glass, condensation

What are tips to paint on privacy for bathroom windows?  White spray paint sounds easy, but would make it harder to clean the window, would it not?

Pros: Privacy with natural light. Window shades stay open while showering which keeps the condensation away, thus improving life of wood window frame.

Cons:  Unless the paint dries smooth-as-glass, it will collect dust much more quickly and be more difficult to clean.

What are professional tips to apply paint to windows for bathroom privacy and ease-of-cleaning?  Electrostatic paint?

Answer (score 6):

Have you thought of a bathroom window film? It's very easy to put there, and it works really nicely. I mean one of these:

[image]

They  come in a variety of patterns, from plain to very fancy. I think they are easier to apply than the sprays (I've put them on couple windows without any problems). They are made to be in the bathroom so they last long, and the surface is easy to clean from dust.

Comment: @Harper [Do you really think I don't know what "XY problem" means?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/11002)

Comment: It often happens that people from other SE's come to visit this one.  Those communities often have much harsher community standards, and often those are necessary due to the community makeup.  They then try to apply their home stack's standards here.  Mistake.  Double mistake when you yourself have enjoyed the flexibility of our more mellow view.   Ultimately the goal *here* is to be *helpful*.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to paint the window try putting the paint on the outside of the glass. This way the inside where you clean more will still be "smooth as glass" because it will still be glass.

On the other hand there are partially opaque films that you can get that apply from the inside of the glass. They are plastic and clean easily. Plus they are intrinsically more removable should a future owner not want the same level of privacy.

Comment: I was thinking the outside would collect dirt as much as inside, but need to powerwash exterior anyway.

Comment: I agree.  And note that if you use a film it may have issues with condensation/humidity.  There are lots of auto glass specialists that will gladly put privacy film on the outside of your window.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, But I have seen the glass frosting spray a lot. I think it would be a desirable option, since you still get good light through the glass.

[image]

[glass frosting spray](http://www.plasti-kote.co.uk/LIVE_IMAGES/glass_frosting(1).jpg)

Comment: You can also get self adhesive sheets to turn a window into an obscuring window.

Comment: I have successfully used such a spray on the glazed doors of a bathroom cabinet (sprayed on the inside) and my front door (sprayed on the outside). It's been about 5 years, and the coat of spray is still in good condition —  no scratches, no obvious yellowing. However, I only expect to have to clean these panes with an occasional dusting; the spray film can be scored through with a determined fingernail scratch. I also sincerely doubt it would resist the application of cleaning chemicals (though you could simply respray when necessary). *Paint* is not suitable — it's too hard to apply evenly.